# Upload audio files from html5 web application in Safari iPad

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, file-upload, safari

Im building a web application that must run in iPad. The problem i have is that i give the user the posibility to upload videos, images and audio. The two first ones i make them like this:

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*">
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

And both work perfect. But when i do:

```
<input type="file" accept="audio/*">
```

Its like ignores the "accept" parameter in iPad devices. And when i use that input the device only lets me choose photo or video.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm curious as to how you're getting sound files on your device to begin with. Are they being saved from the web?

Comment: I don't know. You said that there is no way to have sound files in your iPad?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem right now and I think I could solve it by using this code:

```
<input type="file" accept="audio/mp3, audio/wav">
```

MacOS as well as iOS seem to acknowledge the accept values.

Here is a link to all supported media types:
[Apple Safari Web Content Guide - Use Supported iOS Rich Media MIME Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW7)

Answer (score 0):

If the elegant way does not work, you may try the more verbose one. According to [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp), you should be able to define a list of accepted file extensions:

```
<input type="file" accept=".wav,.aif,.aiff,.flac,.alac,.aac,.ogg,.mp3">
```

I did not test it and I don't know if it's case sensitive, but you could give it a try, and adapt the list to your need.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. As listed here https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-accept currently (iOS 12 - 12.1): "Supports the type format (e.g. image/*) but not the extension format (e.g. .png)". Additionally, even though Safari claims to support the type format they really only support "video/*" and "image/*", and ignore "audio/*". (great job Apple)